# Get maximum and minimum values on dict with list values

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, max, min

The dict is

```
mydict = {'A': [10, 9, 8], 'B': [2,3,4,5]})
```

Output needed

```
Max A=10, Min A=8
Max B=5, Min B=2
```

Is there any way to do it? I am using `defaultdict` from `collections` and appending the values in the middle of the program so I don't know the key and values until the block gets completed.

Comment: ```max(mydict.get('A'))```

Comment: I dono the key and value.. It generates in the middle.. I cant pass keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `items`:

```
for k,v in mydict.items():
    print(f'Max {k}={max(v)}, Min {k} ={min(v)}')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go over the dictionary's items, and extract the min and max of each value. With a comprehension statement, this can even be a oneliner:

```py
print('\n'.join(f'Max {k}={max(v)}, Min {k}={min(v)}' for k,v in mydict.items()))
```